# helm camunda chart giving error during deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, camunda, helm3

I am trying to deploy my camunda Kubernetes cluster using helm charts but getting errors again and again. I am pasting the error screenshot down below. Please check and reply if you know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Looks like you already have some resources in the namespace with same name of the one expected by the chart. Maybe an earlier failed installation? Can you do a helm ls?

Comment: please dont post screenhots. Copy the console output into a fenced codeblock instead.

Comment: @AndD I checked with the helm ls command. I got nothing. No resources were there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
kubectl get secrets
```

to check existing secrets. It looks like the secret camunda-bpm-platform-db-credentials already exists.

You should then be able to use

```
kubectl delete camunda-bpm-platform-db-credentials
```

to clean this up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not getting the above issue now but the thing is I am getting a different error now. Basically, I am using the RDS database in camunda and configured it but I am getting this error when I run `kubectl describe <containr_name>`.  **Error: couldn't find key postgres in Secret default/camunda-bpm-platform-db-credentials**

Comment: kubectl edit secrets camunda-bpm-platform-db-credentials

Comment: I tried to edit the secrets file but the value is the same at both places.